# Math error in angularjs calculation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am calculating the values and dividing the total by variable value (9).for example:

```
$scope.wald_costs = Math.round($scope.logistics_costs + $scope.refurbishment_costs + $scope.insurance_costs + $scope.priceful + $scope.t / $scope.$scope.sharable_with)
```

which will be

```
$scope.wald_costs = Math.round(1000 + 500 + 4500 + 45000 + 27000 / 9)
```

suppose to be `$scope.wald_costs = 8666`
but i am not getting the proper output when i print  `<b>{{wald_costs}}</b>`.
Instead what i get in output is like this `6000450003375`

```
$scope.t = 27000 
$scope.logistics_costs = 1000
$scope.refurbishment_costs = 500
$scope.insurance_costs = 4500
$scope.priceful = 45000
$scope.sharable_with = 9

$scope.wald_costs = Math.round(($scope.logistics_costs + $scope.refurbishment_costs + $scope.insurance_costs + $scope.priceful + $scope.t / $scope.$scope.sharable_with))
```

how can i solve this?

Comment: If it's supposed to be `8666` then you need to add some parenthesis.

Comment: Is a typo or you divide only `$scope.t` by `$scope.sharable_with`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://plnkr.co/edit/8ZZY2XtxB2EbB64hWYyn?p=preview

```
$scope.t = 27000; 
$scope.logistics_costs = 1000;
$scope.refurbishment_costs = 500;
$scope.insurance_costs = 4500;
$scope.priceful = 45000;
$scope.sharable_with = 9;
$scope.wald_costs = Math.round(($scope.logistics_costs + $scope.refurbishment_costs + $scope.insurance_costs + $scope.priceful + $scope.t) / $scope.sharable_with);
  alert($scope.wald_costs);
```

Comment: I tried it, but its concatenating all numbers instead of adding.

Comment: what is your expected output , see the plnkr link .

Comment: Thanks i solved it. one of the scope variable had text instead of number thats why it was causing problem...

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$scope.wald_costs = Math.round(($scope.logistics_costs + $scope.refurbishment_costs + $scope.insurance_costs + $scope.priceful + $scope.t) / $scope.$scope.sharable_with)
```